How to use ftp-simple in vs code?

This is my setting.
However, it only comes out to ftp open, and the file list is not imported.

In addition to setting the firewall, I tried setting ftp-simple: remote-workspace-load-all of vs code to false.
I can connect, but the file list is not getting it, how do I solve it?
It's connected to editplus, so I think it's only a matter of vs code.
Connection by using vs code.
